# Upgraded to 18.04 and it is incredibly slow

Tags: systemd, cpu-load, dnsmasq

I'm running an i7 quad core with 16gb ram and an SSD. My proc maxes out at 100% routinely, and sometimes my ram goes into swap. 
This happens with Gnome or Unity. My laptop runs arch, and I'm seriously thinking of jumping ship, even if installing arch is a massive pita.

The 'top' command shows a process called "Web Content". That and systemd-resolve, and occasionally dnsmasq are gunking up my CPU resources. 
What do I do?

Comment: "Web Content" is a process associated to Firefox most likely.

Comment: Thanks for that detail.  I was starting to wonder if my computer hadn't been compromised.

Comment: I would recommend to try running the computer offline to see if it still hogs up cpu that way, since 'Web Content' along with a resolver sounds awfully related to bad network activity.

Answer (score 0):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304050/how-to-avoid-conflicts-between-dnsmasq-and-systemd-resolved

Asked too soon. Apparently....setting DNSStubListener to "no" pushed my proc issues down a lot. Apparently, it was an issue between dnsmasq and systemd-resolve

Comment: After this, the highest consuming process in the "top" command is Web Content and gnome-shell. Fan has gone quiet. wooo.